# how can i get the selected text from dropdownlistfor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

i have a model :

```
    public class studentmodel
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
        }
```

i populate my dropdown :

```
        // GET: dropdown/Test

    public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
            {
                list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "saurav", Value = "1"});
                list.Add(new SelectListItem {Text = "Rj", Value = "2" });
                list.Add(new SelectListItem {Text = "rahul", Value = "3" });
                ViewBag.studentlist = list;
            }            
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(studentmodel s)
        {          
            return View();
        }
```

i have a controller action which is postback:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Test", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.name, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.studentlist, "select student");

            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="submit" />
            </div>       
                <div> you have selected : @ViewBag.selected </div>        
        }
```

How do i get the text from my drop down list? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use client side javascript as the change happens at the browser.

First change the markup a little bit to wrap the selection in a span.

```
<div> you have selected : <span id="selectedItem">@ViewBag.selected</span> </div>
```

*Remove the `@ViewBag.selected` from the above line if your GET action is not really setting anything to that.*

Now the script

```
$(function(){
   $("#name").change(function(){
      var selected = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
      $("#selectedItem").text(selected);
   });    
});
```

This will read the selected option's Text and set that on our span.

If you want this text in the HttpPost action, you can add a new property to your view model

```
public class studentmodel
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string SelectedText{ get; set; }
}
```

And keep a hidden field inside the form

```
@Html.HiddenFor(s=>s.SelectedText)
```

Now, set the value of this using javascript set the value of this hidden field.

```
$(function(){
   $("#name").change(function(){
      var selected = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
      //var selected = $("#name option:selected").text(); // another option
      $("#selectedItem").text(selected);
      $("#SelectedText").val(selected);
   });    
});
```

Now when you submit the form, the value of the hidden field `SelectedText` will also be submitted.

Comment: i am looking only for c# no anyother javascript code.

Comment: you need js as the change event happens at client side

Answer (score 0):

**Model**  add one viewmodel as below

```
 public class studentmodel
 {
     public int id { get; set; }
     public string name { get; set; }
 }

 public class SomeViewModel
 {
    public string studentname {get; set;}
    public SelectList studentlist {get; set;}

 }
```

**Updated**

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
      SomeViewModel Model = new SomeViewModel();
      var studentlist = new List<SelectListItem>();
      studentlist.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "saurav" });
      studentlist.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "Rj" });
      studentlist.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "3", Text = "rahul" });
      Model.studentlist = new SelectList(studentlist,     nameof(SelectListItem.Value), nameof(SelectListItem.Text));

      return View(Model);
 }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SomeViewModel s)
    {          
        return View();
    }
```

and change your view as below

**Updated**

```
    @model somenamespace.SomeViewModel
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.studentname , Model.studentlist , "select student");
```

Comment: you are not calling the someviewmodel in to studentmodel then view it wont call model.studentlist and then also have to change in to the controller which is id = "1" it wont it will id = 1 and i want postback so elaborate also

Comment: basically we are calling one class only which is our view model SomeViewModel we bind all data to someviewmodel and pass this mdoel to the view and on post method there is a parameter of viewmodel so basically we are playing with one viewmodel only

Comment: in razor also you have to add this viewmodel **@model.someviewmodel** on the top of razor html like this it will get studentlist

Comment: in razor calling the @model.someviewmodel and adding with Model.studentlist as selectlist the output is ellaborating the model name not the actual name what we want . and with Model.studentlist getting an error.

Comment: thats error now gone after rebuilding now the output is coming somenamespace.model in the dropdownlist

Comment: controller's code has been updated for **Index()** in my answer try this one

Comment: from dropdownlist whatever i have selected that name to be output as a string on the same view

Comment: your postmethod to get name you have to select like this **s.studentname**  in post method

Comment: Make sure your dropdown is filled ?

Comment: i know many ways to filled the dropdownlist but httppost is really pissing me off.

Comment: post method fire than what data is filling there is two fields right? one is studenname and one is studentlist in each field what comes while posting data attach a screenshot if possible